# How to make a simple show/hide button work?

Tags: javascript, html, button, display

I'm just trying to find out... why do I have to click 2x (instead of just 1 click) until the text appears for the first time? Could you give me some help to fix that?
Thanks!

```js
function mudar() {
  var x = document.getElementById("texto");
  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.escondido {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick=mudar()>EXIBIR E ESCONDER O TEXTO</button>
<p class="escondido" id="texto">Texto para exibir e esconder</p>
```

Comment: Wow, many possible solutions, thank you guys very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your program starts, the value of `x.style.display` is not `"none"`, it is the empty string.

Just add:

```js
|| x.style.display == ""
```

And that should work as expected.

```js
function mudar() {
  var x = document.getElementById("texto");
  if (x.style.display == "none" || x.style.display == "") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.escondido {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick=mudar()>EXIBIR E ESCONDER O TEXTO</button>
<p class="escondido" id="texto">Texto para exibir e esconder</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change

```
        if (x.style.display == "none") {
```

to

```
        if (x.style.display === "" || x.style.display == "none") {
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because initially the display property in style is an empty string "". And your code is following through to else block directly. You can add a condition to check if the display property value is an empty string.

```js
function mudar() {
  var x = document.getElementById("texto");
  console.log(x.style.display)
  if (x.style.display == "none" || x.style.display == "") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.escondido {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick=mudar()>EXIBIR E ESCONDER O TEXTO</button>
<p class="escondido" id="texto">Texto para exibir e esconder</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the display property use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) which "returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain"

```js
function mudar() {
  var x = document.getElementById("texto");
  var display = window.getComputedStyle(x).getPropertyValue('display');
  if (display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.escondido {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick=mudar()>EXIBIR E ESCONDER O TEXTO</button>
<p class="escondido" id="texto">Texto para exibir e esconder</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative method, toggling the class, decoupling your styles from your "business logic":

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .escondido {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .escondido-hidden {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick=mudar()>EXIBIR E ESCONDER O TEXTO</button>
  <p class="escondido escondido-hidden" id="texto">Texto para exibir e esconder</p>
  <script>
    function mudar() {
      var x = document.getElementById("texto");
      x.classList.toggle('escondido-hidden')
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```